# Ubuntu 18.04 Keyboard

Tags: keyboard

I recently upgraded to 18.04 - found I'd lost some keyboard taps, such as the "@" but figured out that with the 'number lock' key.

I upgrades my system and now find that every time I press a key, I have to keep it pressed for maybe a second.

I have tried the slow key option without any improvement.

Comment: Did you turn slow keys off?

Comment: Yes indeed..However since my comment I've had a software update, and it seems to have sorted itself out.. How I've no idea, but thank you - tis terrific to know that a novice like myself can ask for help.. And I get it.. Thank you again..

Comment: Spoke too soon, problem has returned, although not quite as bad, but bad enough to be a real pain in the you know what.  Cheers.

Comment: Oe minuteits erfet, en the next t etrensto isig, and slow ys. This is what I have to contend with, it is so erratic. HELP..!! One minute it is good then next, back to the chaos.

Comment: Try creating a new user and logging in as that user. If that fixes it, that narrows it down to something with your user account.

Comment: Thans r that, tried it an  n dffeence whatsoever.

Comment: If it's an attached keyboard, try it on a different computer.

Comment: I use a laptop..  Also, installed a software upgrade, and  now  have no 'number lock' function. Can  now, no longer use right hand  numbers.

Comment: OK, try making an Ubuntu 16.04 live DVD or USB drive. Boot from it, choose to try Ubuntu without installing, and see if the keyboard problem persists.

Comment: Haven't tried that as yet, excepting the numeric right hand keyboard.. All works fine.. For how long is another question.. Now have to research how to make a 16.04 live USB.. Will be back.. Many thanks..